# Windows Server blocking access from OpenVPN connected users

Tags: windows, openvpn, qnap

I have remote users connecting to an internal work network via an OpenVPN service that's running on a QNAP device. The QNAP device is connected to the internal work network and is routing traffic from remote users perfectly well **with one vital exception**. Once users are connected to the VPN they can ping and access services on every network device EXCEPT a Windows Server. They simply can't ping the server and also cannot access file or printer shares hosted on the server.

I suspect that this is a firewall issue on Windows Server itself. I'm guessing the server is blocking access to anyone/anything that's not associated with the AD.

Is this a correct assumption? If so, how do I adjust the firewall and make exceptions for the folks who are connecting via VPN? Any suggestions otherwise?

Thanks.

Comment: Windows Firewall has logs, it should only require a few minutes to confirm.

Comment: temporary disabls the windows firewall and verify this is also a second possibility, but should not be kept off in my mind